# why can't I use if statement with my for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get the binary 0 and 1s of a string so I can transfer it using Li-Fi technology, basically using a led on a raspberry pi to turn on if it is a 1 and turn off if it is a 0.
When I print "bit" it prints the 0 and 1s, but when I use if statements, nothing happens, any idea why?

```
test_str = "hello world"
  

res = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in test_str)
for bit in res:
    #print(bit) //works as I want it
    if bit == 1: 
        print ("x")
    elif bit == 0: 
        print ("y")
```

Comment: `bit` is a string, which you're comparing to integers. You need to use `'1'` and `'0'`.

Comment: To check the variable type, try `print("{}".format(type(bit)))`

Comment: @Franke A simple `print(type(bit))` will do.

Answer (score 3):

Because `res` is a string, not a set of integers.  You would need `bit == '1'` and `bit == '0'`.

However, you don't have to go through strings at all.

```
for c in test_str:
    for bit in range(8):
        if ord(c) & (1 << bit):
            print("x")
        else:
            print("y")
```

Comment: Why does it happen that everytime I know an answer to a question, someone else already answers before me :(

Comment: Just upvoted to highlight that I thought of the same solution :3

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen it happens to everybody.  Keep at it and maybe next time you'll be the first.  It helps if you're a fast typist.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for your kind words of encouragement :) I try my best.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen any idea why Tim's code only prints Xs not Ys? I just read a little about ord() and bit shifting, yet can't figure out why it isn't printing as it should.

Comment: @Husseo19 Investigating, please give me a few minutes.

Comment: Alright, on further investigation it turns out that since `ord(c)` is an ascii character, it is always Truish - since any positive integer is considered `True` in python. And `1 << bit` is yet again always non zero, positive integer, since bit is always in the range: 0...7. So, `1 << bit` will look like: `1`, `2`, `4`, ... (i.ie., powers of 2). So both of these terms: `ord(c)` and `1 << bit` are always Truish, and so their AND is `True`.

Comment: Turns out what Tim intended to do was to take the **first bit** or MSB of `1 << bit` and then use the logical AND with the **corresponding bit** in `ord(c)`, but the logic was a little flawed.

Comment: I posted my own answer which uses encoding and mapping to output the binary format for string. I think it should be more suited to your problem :) Have a nice day!

Comment: Oops, too many ampersands.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [encode method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) of the string object that encodes your string as a bytes object using the passed encoding type. You just need to make sure you pass a proper encoding to encode function.

```
In [9]: "hello world".encode('ascii')                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[9]: b'hello world'

In [10]: byte_obj = "hello world".encode('ascii')                                                                                                                                                           

In [11]: byte_obj                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[11]: b'hello world'

In [12]: byte_obj[0]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[12]: 104
```

Otherwise, if you want them in form of zeros and ones --binary representation-- as a more pythonic way you can first convert your string to byte array then use bin function within map :

```
>>> st = "hello world"
>>> map(bin,bytearray(st))
['0b1101000', '0b1100101', '0b1101100', '0b1101100', '0b1101111', '0b100000', '0b1110111', '0b1101111', '0b1110010', '0b1101100', '0b1100100']
```

Or you can join it:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(st)))
'0b1101000 0b1100101 0b1101100 0b1101100 0b1101111 0b100000 0b1110111 0b1101111 0b1110010 0b1101100 0b1100100'
```

You can then slice the resulting strings to remove the starting `Ob` from them, and iterate over each character (`0`'s and `1`'s) and handle them to print either `x` or `y` as appropriate.

```
test_str = "hello world".encode("ascii")

x = map(bin, bytearray(test_str))

for each_char in x:
    each_char = each_char[2:]
    for each_bit in each_char:
        if each_bit == "1":
            print("x")
        else:
            print("y")
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me :)